# MySQLdb Python: Why do I get "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" on committing an insert?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I've read several other answers, all of which say that it's probably because the cursor needs to be called between calling multiple stored procedures, but I have only called one stored procedure.

Here is a sample of my python:

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(user=mysql_user_name, passwd=mysql_password,
                              host=mysql_host, db=mysql_database)
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.callproc('usp_WeatherForecastDailyInsert', ['2017-05-31', '2017-06-01', 50, 30, 0.5, 'rain', 2, 240, 0.9, 1, 'darksky')
con.commit() # Error is here
con.close()
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`roei`@`%` PROCEDURE `usp_WeatherForecastDailyInsert`(
  forecasted_time datetime,
  prediction_time datetime,
  temperature_max float,
  temperature_min float,
  precip_chance float,
  precip_type varchar(50),
  wind_speed float,
  wind_bearing float,
  humidity float,
  location_id int,
  service_name varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
    select @service_id := S.id
    from main_weatherservice S
    where S.short_name = service_name;

    start transaction;

    insert into main_weatherforecast
    (
        forecasted_time,
        prediction_time,
        temperature_max,
        temperature_min,
        precip_chance,
        precip_type,
        wind_speed,
        wind_bearing,
        humidity,
        location_id,
        service_id
    )
    values
    (
        forecasted_time,
        prediction_time,
        temperature_max,
        temperature_min,
        precip_chance,
        precip_type,
        wind_speed,
        wind_bearing,
        humidity,
        location_id,
        @service_id
    );
END
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the commit inside of the stored procedure instead of inside the python code?

Comment: @ChatterOne That seems to work, thanks. Any idea as to why it didn't work with the normal commit function?

Comment: Because that's two separate "threads" (well, not really "threads", maybe more "environments"), which means that it's as if you tried to nest a transaction inside of another transaction.